# Multiple canvas, reusable gradients

Tags: jquery, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to write dry code for multiple canvas. I am applying gradients to chartjs charts and don't want to rewrite the same gradient for each chart instance.

```
var ctx1 = $("#SoftwareChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = $("#WebChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

var gradient1 = ctx1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient1.addColorStop(0, '#ff9170');   
gradient1.addColorStop(1, '#ff3f05');

var gradient2 = ctx1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient3.addColorStop(0, '#f5d147');   
gradient3.addColorStop(1, '#dfb30c');

var gradient1 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient1.addColorStop(0, '#ff9170');   
gradient1.addColorStop(1, '#ff3f05');

var gradient2 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
gradient3.addColorStop(0, '#f5d147');   
gradient3.addColorStop(1, '#dfb30c');
```

As you can see, this is not very dry, and I hate it. Is there a way to .getContext on all the canvas I want to use and apply the gradients to all of them at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I used chart.js, I had 17 different charts to create.

As long as you can easily grab all of your `canvas` tags, you can add them all to a object array like this:

```
//Get array of all canvases on the DOM
var chartCount = $('canvas').length;

for (var i = 1; i < chartCount; i++) {
    //Get DOM element of canvas
    var el = $('chart').get(i);

    //Add new entry to canvas array with DOM element and canvas context
    canvas[i] = {
        'DOM_Element': el,
        'context': el.getContext('2d')
    };
}
```

Then each canvas context can be referenced with something like `canvas[x]['context']`.

You could then write a function to loop through all entires in the canvas array adding gradients as desired.